# my code is giving an error that Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
**const url = 'https://weather-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/weather?city=Seattle';
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '2048170619msh07914b56695e5eap11cf22jsneef2a005b0b9',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'weather-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};
try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const result = await response.text();
    console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}**
```

i want to use this api but this error is coming :
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: The error speaks for itself, but if you have no experience with async/await, here's a good start: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: const fetchAPI = async () => {
  .... your code
}

Comment: you should use `<script type="module">` to have a top-level `await`.

Answer (score 0):

The faster solution is wrap your code in a async function and call te function:

```js
**const url = 'https://weather-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/weather?city=Seattle';
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '2048170619msh07914b56695e5eap11cf22jsneef2a005b0b9',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'weather-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};
async function run(){
  try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const result = await response.text();
      console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
  }**
}
run();
```

Comment: yeah! I have done this and it works.